# SwiftのMetalで型変換ができない

Tags: swift, objective-c

こんにちは、Objective-CからSwiftへの移植中に以下の代入部分で変換が出来なくなり、質問させて頂きました。

Source Code

```
let positionsArray: vector_float3 = _templeVertexPositions.contents()
```

Origin Code

```
vector_float3 *positionsArray = (vector_float3 *)_templeVertexPositions.contents;
```

Error Code

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' to specified type 'vector_float3' (aka 'SIMD3<Float>')
```

移植を行なっているコード
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/migrating_opengl_code_to_metal

*vector_float3*でも変換できず困っています。
型が違う配列同士を変換すれば出来そうな気はするのですが、解決出来ません。
何か良い方法があればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score -1):

自己解決出来ました！

let positionsArray: [vector_float3] = [vector_float3](_immutableCocoaArray: _templeVertexPositions)

※追記　多分、こっちの方が正しそうです
let positionsArray: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = _templeVertexPositions.contents()